# CSS not working correctly on IE 7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, hyperlink, alignment

I am working on a website curently. Here is the [link](http://www.movend.com) for it.

Good News : The site is fine on FireFox, Chrome and IE 8.

Bad News: It is not fine on IE 7. Alignment problems, hyperlink colour problems, etc.

What should i do to make things normal on IE7 too.
Any amount of help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to programming CSS in Internet Explorer, the cause of loss of millions of man hours of work around the world.

There are probably too many small issues to go through fixing them for you, the best thing to do is fully test each feature in all browsers as you develop, not at the end.

Good luck.

Comment: Oh no... So what should i do now ? I have almost finished everything... I was looking into IE8 while developing. It was fine... Please help me

Comment: Don't worry!  IE has lots of non standards compliant crap, along with a whole load of unexplainable crap which is a headache for all developers, best thing is to isolate one problem at a time and hone in on it, trying different techniques to find one that suits all browsers.  Try to avoid using 'browser' detecting Javascript code etc, that is unreliable, attempt to find a CSS/HTML solution for all the problems.

Comment: Let me guess... IE6 is next? :)

Answer (score 3):

Nice looking site.

As for IE7, my IE7 developer toolbar is playing up so I can't see what the exact problem is. Seeing as the site validates and the other browsers are close, I'd look at using conditional comments to serve extra CSS for IE7.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Yes. I agree with the group. You're going to have to test your css styles by hand. If it's any consolation, IETester might be of some peripheral help: http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

That said, I wouldn't worry too much about styling IE7. Here's why: it looks like you're catering to developers and smart-phone-savvy users. If your developers or your "savvy" users are still using IE7, you probably have much bigger problems. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there's no standard solution to your problem. You have to go through trial and error modification to your CSS files.

Even people with plenty of experience with HTML/CSS still get mismatches from IE7 (which is still wayyyyy better than IE6).

Good luck.